# If cigarettes are Haram why are many Muslims smoking shisha?

Tags: halal-haram, smoking

As per subject I see a lot of Muslims where I live that have Shisha and cigarettes. Isn't this Haram? Aren't cigarettes Haram too or is Shisha considered Hakroon (something like prawns, which is sort of undefined)?

Comment: From my point of view, I think it is because Halal and Haram nowadays is more about social ethics (dominating in one given society at a given time) than about religion. Just see how female smokers are denigrated in these societies, utter nonsense.

Comment: Because many many Muslims do things that are Haram, this doesn't mean they are no longer Muslims, this mean that they are feeble. Those who say that it's not Haram want to find pretexts for themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all i think you are trying to say MAKROOH by the word Hakroom.
So, there are both opinions that cigarettes are makrooh and haram, but the second opinion that cigarettes are haraam seems more reasonable.
And on the basis of same reasons built for cigarette to be haraam, sheesha is also haraam(or if someone goes with first opinion of makrooh it is makrooh).
If someone is doing something, it doesnot define what his religion's ruling is about that thing.
 In the same way as Most of the muslims in the world now a days are connected to banking system which is based on interest (riba) which is haraam in islam, this doesn't mean that interest is halal or permissible in islam.